# Binding controls on PreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, prerender

I have been led to believe that the best point to bind your controls is the PreRender.  As all the controls are ready and this is the last stage before rendering etc. Is this correct or should controls be bound at a different point?

Many Thanks

Louis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with binding at `PreRender`.
Refer to [the life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).
As you can see, `PreRender` occurs after the control events (such as clicking), which is essential when having to rebind new/modified data after the users submits the form with a click of some sort.

But if you do not have to do binding based on user interactivity, then for the most part the place you put is irrelevant.

Make no mistake, though, depending on your logic, some bindings may have to occur before the control events for them to interact with the bound data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the page life "bible" that I use!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

I would bind your controls at Page_Load

Comment: Binding at page load would cause not taking changes by events into account

Comment: @Gluip What's the problem with biniding in the event method itself ? no need for pre_render.